# Can I use ImageMap and require editors to login in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I can't edit a page using the imagemap tag when logged in.
This is for a mediawiki installation where all editors must be logged in.

Page is at
http://mediawiki.owenks.uk/wiki/index.php?title=ImageMapPage

If I change the permissions and allow all users to edit, then I can save the page.  But if I change permissions back to 
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
then login and try to edit the page, I get a blank screen after hitting "Save Page".

I tried to ask on the mediawiki help site but was unable to post.

Any suggestions?

MediaWiki   1.24.1
PHP     5.6.4 (cgi-fcgi)
MariaDB     5.5.41-MariaDB-1~wheezy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was nothing to do with ImageMap.  Was a conflict with GraphViz extension. Removing the GraphViz extension put everything back to normal.